# When I refresh the page my array is back to original, singleton not working?

Tags: php, singleton

It doesn't save my changes after adding a category.
If I add a category, it is seen in the overview, but if I refresh I see the original amount.
I guess there is an error in my Singleton-design but I can't seem to find it.

```
class ProductService {

    private $_database;

    public function __construct($databaseType) {
        $databaseFactory = new DatabaseFactory();
        $this->_database = $databaseFactory->createDatabase($databaseType);
    }

    public function addCategory($category){
        $this->_database->addCategory($category);
    }

    public function getAllCategories() {
        return $this->_database->getAllCategories();
    }
}

class DatabaseFactory {

    public function __construct() {        
    }

    public function createDatabase($type){
        switch ($type) {
            case "Memory" : 
                return MemoryDatabase::getInstance();
        }
    }
}

class MemoryDatabase {

    private $categories;

    private function __construct() {
        $this->categories = array(
            new Category("Cheese"),
        );
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        static $inst = null;
        if ($inst === null) {
            $inst = new MemoryDatabase();
        }
        return $inst;
    }

    private function __clone() {}

    private function __wakeup() {}

    public function addCategory($category) {
        array_push($this->categories, $category);
    }

    public function getAllCategories() {
        return $this->categories;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each request you perform in PHP is stateless.

If you want to persist data between requests, you will need to put your data in some form of persistant storage, i.e., sessions, filesystem, database, memory, etc.

Singleton pattern only ensures a single copy of an object is created, **for a given request**.

Comment: @user3704860 If you found my answer the most helpful, please do not forget to mark my answer as the best.